# Сортировка списка кортежей Python

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать список из кортежей по лексикографическому порядку (по алфавиту), но с учетом 2-го параметра.

Имеется список:

```
('my', 2)
('ding', 2)
('oh', 1)
('you', 1)
('touch', 1)
('tralala', 1)
('mmm', 1)
('dong', 1)
```

Его надо отсортировать по `i[0]`, но сохранив порядок 2-го значения.
Т.е. должно получиться:

```
ding
my
dong
mmm
oh
touch
tralala
you
```

Я понимаю, что должно что-то использоваться типа `sort where i[1] ==`  и так далее, но что-то не придумывается.

Спасибо.

Comment: `список.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))`

Comment: @andreymal Не желаете опубликовать как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 неа (удалённый по-моему тоже неплох, демонстрирует устойчивость сортировки)

Comment: @BeerAndBear значит вы нас обманули и список на самом деле не такой, какой вы показали в вопросе

Comment: @andreymal Возможно, я действительно не прав и где-то ошибся.

Сейчас в итоге решил немного по другому, сделаю ответ и впишу входные данные + сам код.

Comment: @andreymal написал ниже. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Входные данные:

```
oh you touch my tralala
mmm my ding ding dong
```

Код, который сортирует слова в порядке неубывания + в лексографическом (алфавитном) порядке.

```
descriptor = open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
myDict = dict()
for stroka in descriptor:
    for bukva in stroka.split():
        if myDict.get(bukva, 0) == 0:
            myDict[bukva] = 1
        else:
            x = myDict[bukva] + 1
            myDict[bukva] = x
            x = 0
myDict2 = sorted(myDict)
temp1 = sorted(myDict2, key=lambda x: myDict[x], reverse=True)
for i in temp1:
    print(i)
```

Результат:

```
ding
my
dong
mmm
oh
touch
tralala
you
```

Comment: Можно импортировать collections и в одну строку `for x in sorted(collections.Counter(open('input.txt', 'r').read().split()).items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])): print(x[0])`

Comment: @andreymal Действительно. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: (хотя файл всё-таки лучше открывать через `with open` и сделать побольше строк ради читабельности)

Comment: @andreymal  и тут соглсен. Но, учусь на онлайн курсах, и требования - никаких лишних пробелов и считывание в таком формате. Если интересует - то это coursera.